# Express Gateway Command Line Interface 'eg'

Tags: command-line-interface, express-gateway

Can some one help me with installing 
Command Line Interface 'eg' for express gateway.
on windows10 machine 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

the command line tool for Express Gateway is bundled with the gateway itself. Therefore, `nom i -g express-gateway` should be all you need to do to have the CLI in place, as long the npm binary path is set in your local `PATH` env variable.

Does that answer your question?